# About Goddess Ashvaroodha Devi

Tags: goddess, parvati, dasha-mahavidya

Has anyone heard about Aswarooda Devi?

if yes, please explain the importance of this Goddess.
is the worship only for some special purposes? or can it be a part of daily prayer?
What's her moolamantra && what's the Dhyanam?

Comment: Please limit your question to a single question. You ask multiple questions. You are asking all about the goddess now. Why is she not one of the goddesses is a distinct question. You are not limited to a single question on the site. You can post different questions on each topic. Asking many questions will lead for closure of the question as too broad. Please be clear in the title. It's looking like click bait.

Comment: okay Ji . 've edited the question

Comment: Can you please let me know the link for tantra chat room _/\_

Comment: @SaMolPP Here it is:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AswArudha Devi is mentioned in the 3rd UllAsha (3rd Chapter) of the [Nityotsava](http://www.shivashakti.com/nityot.htm). This chapter is called Shri Krama. So, AswArudhA worship is done as an Anga-UpAsanA of Shri VidyA.

I do not know whether she is worshipped outside Shri VidyA UpAsanA or not.

Her Mantra and DhyAnam are mentioned in the *RashmimAlA Mantram* section of the 3rd Chapter of the book.  The Viniyogah portion of her Mantra is as follows:

> AswArudhA mantrasya brahmA rishih | GAyatri chandah | aswArudhA devatA
>   | Tat prasAd siddhArthe jape viniyogah ||
>
> For the AswArudhA Mantra, the Seer is Lord BrahmA, metre is GAyatri,
>   Deity is AswArudhA, for achieving her blessings I am doing this Japa.

**DhyAnam:**

> VaddhA pAshena ankushena krishyamAnAsva sAdhyakam |
>  Gnantim
>   vetrena phAla srak pAnim aswAsanAm bhaje ||
>
> One who binds and pulls the to-be-won horse with the help of PAsha and
>   Ankusha and whips it, who is decorated with garlands of flower on the
>   breasts and on the hands, I salute that horse-seated Goddess.

So, not only she will ride a horse another way of identifying the Goddess is by seeing the golden whip she holds in her hand.

Another DhyAnam is also given in the book and which is as follows:

> AswArudhA karAgre navakanaka mayim vetra jashtim dadhAnA |
>   Dakshehanye dhArayanti sphurati dhanur latA pAsha hastA susAdhyA |
>   Devi nitya prasannA shashi shakalal sat kesha pAshA trinetrA |
>   DadyAdAdyAna vadyAm sriyam khila sukha prApti hridyAm shriyei nah ||
>
> The Devi who rides a horse, whose right hand has a whip made of pure
>   gold, whose other hand is holding a bow, with other hands she is holding a
>   creeper and Ankusha (goad); Who can be pleased well, who is eternally
>   blissful, in whose hairs shines the moon, let that Goddess manifest.
>   Since she provides spectacular Shri (wealth) which results in infinite
>   bliss, she is dear to the heart (Hridya PriyA). Let she bestow us with such
>   Shri.

The Mantra is also given in the book and  I can post it. But it is part of RashmimAlA Mantras and should not be chanted without initiation. So, I am somewhat reluctant. The book also gives the same warning by quoting a verse from a Tantra.

All I can say about the Mantra is it ends with "Parameswari SwAhA" and after the Mantra it states " Iyam Shridevi pratyangabhutA AswArudhA" which refers to AswArudhA as being born from the body of the Supreme Devi (LalitA).

Answer (score 2):

Ashvaroodha is a goddess which has a horse as her vehicle. She is popular in the region of Kerala.

Her upasana can be daily as well as for special purposes. She is normally worshiped as an anga devata as a part of Sri vidya upasana.

Mantra cannot be revealed here.

Not to forget that one must be initiated in her worship for doing the mantra.